# How can I access the index outside *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use the variable `i` outside of my ngFor. What options are there to solve this problem?

Here is a small application example:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let selection of selectionNumber; index as i;">
        <app-MyDropdown
          tabindex="{{i}}"
        ></app-MyDropdown
></ng-container>
<div>
    <button
      type="button"
      tabindex="{{i+1}}"
    >
      Button 1
    </button>
    <button
      type="button"
      color="primary"
      tabindex="i+2"
    >
      Button 2
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to use the `i` variable outside of the for loop to set the tab index. For this `i` should have the last value from the loop iteration.

Comment: Doesn't really make sense. Your buttons only render once. The value of `i` is never anything other than the last iteration index of the loop. If all you want is that quantity, check the length of `selectionNumber` (or just use it directly).

Comment: Angular and AngularJS are different. Please only tag with the one that's relevant.

Comment: I didn't post an answer, and you shouldn't request help from folks like that. I've already seen that post and can't help at this time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use any value of *ngFor outside of whichever element you're running your ngFor loop in, (in your case that is ng-container). Which means you have to put your buttons inside of your ngContainer which will create button. But not sure if that's what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You can not access any data of *ngFor from outside of the loop